# Re-hosted workflow designer - read-only view

Tags: .net-3.5, workflow-foundation, designer

I have re-hosted the workflow designer in my own application. Now I want to make the workflow view read-only. I know I can disallow drag&drop but delete and move should also be disabled. I still want the user to be able to scroll in the view.

Can anyone help.

Best regards,
Michael

Answer (score 5):

You can access the designer view in order to do things like this.

```
var designerView = myDesigner.Context.Services.GetService<DesignerView>();
```

Then set to readonly mode.

```
designerView.IsReadOnly = true;
```

This will also make the property view readonly - not sure if that is what you require or not.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with this solutaion:

1. Created a MessageFilter inherited from WorkflowDesignerMessageFilter and attached it to the WorkflowView.
2. Override method OnKeyDown

   ```
       if (eventArgs.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
       {
           if(m_WorkflowView.AllowDrop)
           {
               return base.OnKeyDown(eventArgs);
           }
       }
       return true;
   ```

In this case I set AllowDrop to false on read-only view and true in DesignTime. If anyone has a better suggestion, please let me know.

Best regards,
Michael